# Annoying Notice: Undefined index: code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been looking the answer of this problem for 3 hours already but i cant remove this annoying notice...can anyone help me please...it keeps pop-ping 'Notice: Undefined index: code.

heres the code:

```
 <?php
    function randomcode() {
        $var = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
        $i = 0;
        $code = '' ;
        while ($i <= 7) {
            $num = rand() % 33;
            $tmp = substr($var, $num, 1);
            $code = $code . $tmp;
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }
    ?>
    <!--scripts ends here-->

    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
       $fname = $_POST['fname'];
       $lname = $_POST['lname'];
       $position = $_POST['position'];
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $gender = $_POST['gender'];
       $repcode = $_POST['code'];
       $contact = $_POST['contact'];
       $age = $_POST['age'];
       $dateregistered = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       if (!$_POST['fname'] || !$_POST['lname'] || !$_POST['position'] || !$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'] || !$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['gender'] || !$_POST['code'] || !$_POST['conctact'] || !$_POST['age'] || !$_POST['code'] ){
           ?>
             <script>
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                    // show a dialog box when clicking on a link

                          $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Try Again! </strong>' +
                             'You did not complete all of the required fields!', {
                             'type':     'warning',
                             'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)'
                        });

                 });
              </script>
       <?php
       }
       else
       {
          $query="INSERT INTO users (position, fname, lname, username,password,dateregistered,repcode,email,age,gender,contact)   VALUES ('$position','$fname','$lname','$username','$password',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$repcode','$email','$age','$gender','$contact') ";
          mysql_query($query);
          if($query){
                 // append here your jquery code
            ?>
              <script>
                 $(document).ready(function() {
                    // show a dialog box when clicking on a link
    $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Congratulations! </strong> <br> ' +
        'You have successfully registered!', {
        'type':     'confirmation',
        'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)'
    });
                 });
              </script>
             <?php
          }
       }
    }
    //corrected indentation
    ?>
```

code:

```
<form action="registration.php" method="post">
<table align="center" width="100%" height="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
<tr> 
<td align="center"> 
<table width="100%"> 
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif" size="+2" color="#333333"><center>Registration Area</center></font>
<table border width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>First Name:</font>
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Rep Code:</font>
    <input type="text" name="code" disabled value="<?php echo randomcode() ?>" STYLE="color: #FF3; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #72A4D2;" >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Last Name:</font>
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>E-mail:</font>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Rank:</font>
<select name="position" style="WIDTH: 200px">
<option></option>
<option>PINSP</option>
<option>PSINSP</option>
<option>PCINSP</option>
<option>PSUPT</option>
<option>PSSUPT</option>
<option>PCSUPT</option>
<option>NUP 1st level Rep.</option>
<option>NUP 2nd level Rep.</option>
<option>NUP 3rd level Rep.</option>
</select>
</td>
<td> | </td>
<td>
<font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Age:</font>
<input type="text" name="age">
</td>
<tr>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Username:</font>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Gender:</font>
    <select name="gender" style="WIDTH: 200px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Password:</font>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    </td>
    <td> | </td>
    <td>
    <font color='dark orange'>*</font><font color='black'>Contact number:</font>
    <input type="text" name="contact">
    </td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Create Account" name="save" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i tired many tutorials already to remove this kind of error but none work...i need your help guys :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` element won't be posted to sever.

Here, you disabled the input element with name `code`, so `$_POST['code']` will cause undefined index notice.

```
<input type="text" name="code" disabled value="<?php echo randomcode() ?>" STYLE="color: #FF3; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #72A4D2;" >
```

Comment: how make my input text untypeable without using disable?

Comment: @eloginko You could use `readonly`